# Powershell script to delete documents from sharepoint library from a csv file with document URL

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2013, delete-file

I am trying to create a powershell script which will delete documents from our on premise share point library. The list of documents to be deleted is specified in a CSV File which has full document URL and File name. These documents are spread across different site collections. Any leads on similar script will be helpful

Comment: What is your current state? Is there anything you have tried? Any problems? Generally it is easier if you have a specific question and are not asking for a finalized solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sample script for your reference.

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}

$fileList =Get-Content C:\Lee\Script\input.csv | Select -skip 1 | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header FileUrl,FileName
#$fileList = import-csv -path "C:\Lee\Script\input.csv" -header FileUrl,FileName
foreach ($line in $fileList)
{
    $fileUrl=$line.FileUrl
    $site = New-Object -Type Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite -ArgumentList $fileUrl
    $web = $site.OpenWeb()  
    $file = $web.GetFile($fileUrl)
    $file.Delete()
    Write-Host "Delete file $($fileUrl) in $($Web.Title)"
}


FileUrl,FileName
http://site/MyDoc/test.docx,test.docx
http://differentsite/MyDoc/test.docx,test.docx
```